# how to update delivery status in PHP using android

Tags: android

I don't even know I am right are wrong. My situation of thinking is currently null. can some please tell me how to update `deliverystatus`

This is code in `AdapterClass`

```
delivered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String serverURL= PathUrls.pathUrl+"evs_updatedeliverystatus.php?db="+companyName.getString("companyName","")+"&invoiceid="+dlb.getInvoiceNo()+"&deliverystatus=1";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(serverURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("update delivery list",response.toString());
                deliveryListBeans.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error DeliveryList:%n %s ", error);
                Toast.makeText(ct,"NetworkError Not Responding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(ct, "companyName"+companyName.getString("companyName","").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
});
```

Comment: We can understand you are new to SO. But can you also write something on what you are looking for. :)

Comment: I am about to update delivery status=1 for particular list view